# python pandas DataFrame аналог partition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

У меня есть дата фрейм:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({'name': ['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb', 'bb'], 'sum': [10, 2, 1, 3, 8, 5, 7, 3, 11]})
```

выглядит он соответственно так:

```
   name  sum
0   aa   10
1   aa    2
2   aa    1
3   aa    3
4   aa    8
5   bb    5
6   bb    7
7   bb    3
8   bb   11
```

мне надо получить из него такое:

```
   name  sum
0   aa   10
1   aa    8
2   aa    3
3   bb   11
4   bb    7
5   bb    5
```

т.е. выбрать по n (в примере 3) максимальных значения каждого name.
можно ли это сделать не в цикле? (примерно как partition в oracle) потому что я делаю в цикле, но думаю можно как-то по эффективнее

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не важен порядок name, по нему можно не сортировать

```
df.sort_values(['name','sum'], ascending = [True,False]).groupby('name').head(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться [df.groupby(...).nlargest()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html):

```
In [12]: df.groupby("name")["sum"].nlargest(3).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
Out[12]:
  name  sum
0   aa   10
1   aa    8
2   aa    3
3   bb   11
4   bb    7
5   bb    5
```